# Cannot read property 'roles' of null discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a script where if a user is muted, it will unmute it, but I can't find the member that has the muted role.

My code:

```js
if (message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.id).roles.has(role => role.name === "Muted")) {
    message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.id).roles.remove(role => role.name === "Muted")
} else if (!message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.id).roles.has(role => role.name === "Muted")) {
    message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.id).roles.add(role => role.name === "Muted")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search through the member's roles to see if they have the *Muted* role:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!member) return message.reply('You didn't mention a user to (un)mute.');

if (member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Muted')) {
  member.roles.remove('Muted');
} else {
  member.roles.add('Muted');
}
```

If you want to find the properties and methods of certain objects, check the [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).